# Java memory management Objects vs Primitive Types

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jvm

I am getting a bit confused regarding few points regarding Java memory management.

Understood what is the difference between Stacks and Heap and I went to see a proper example on what is those memories when we execute some code.

I took for example this few lines

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a = 5;
    calculate(a);
    System.out.println(a); //will print 5 not 50
}
private static void calculatee(int a)
{
    a = a * 10;
}
```

I understood what is happening in the stack and in the heap. The variable is not getting returned and there is no reference to the Heap in this case.

while in this example:

```
public static void maina(String[] args)
{
    Customer customer = new Customer("John");
    setAName(customer);
    System.out.println(customer.getName()); // this will return Philip
}

private static void setAName(Customer c)
{
    c.setName("Philip");
}
```

I can see the state of the object changed this time!

Stacks are not shared thought threads, but heap is shared! Which make sense to me that the object customer has changed its value from Jhon to Philip when I am printing it!
Great! all make sense!

However, I was expecting that if I will do this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Integer i = new Integer(5);
    calculate(i);
    System.out.println(i); // printing 5 and not 50
}
private static void calculate(Integer i)
{
    i = i * 10;
}
```

I would get 50 and not 5!

In this case Integer is an object and I am assuming it is created in the heap!

Funny thing is that if I will wrap the Integer inside Customer I will get 50 instead of 5.

Why is this happening? Isn't the Integer type getting created in the Heap?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

(Nothing to do with heaps and stacks, your terminology is confused.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of references and not of heaps and stacks.

When calling the method `calculate`, you pass a reference (in your case, `i` from `main`).

The trick is, that Java will create a new reference inside of `calculate`. So `i` inside of `calculate` and `i` inside of `main` might initially "point" to the same object, but they are not the "same".

So, if you change `i` inside of `calculate` to the object resulting from your multiplication, you don't automatically change the reference of the `i` inside of `main`.

With `Customer`, it's different. You never change where `c` in `setAName` points to. You change one reference *inside* of the object, but both `customer` inside of `main` and `c` in `setAName` still point to that one object!

Here two shitty Paint drawings to explain what I mean (numbers prefixed with `0x` are references):

**For the Integer example:**

[image: Integer Graph]

**For the Customer example:**

[image: Customer Graph]

Don't hesitate to come back with any questions.

I hope this helps.

Comment: got it... If i will try to do a "c = new Cusotmer (...)" inside of setAName() I will actually no change on the customer value... That happens cause name is a member variable. thank you very much

Comment: @OEH good idea! Welcome to the world of immutability, where a reference, once set, will never be changed again. (Instead, any transformation will result in a "new" object). This allows you to think more simply about your code, as you never have to remember where an object might be changed - it won't. In Java, this can be enforced by using `final`.